# Unicode object to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, nltk, python-unicode

I have a utf8 - text corpus I can read easily in Python 2.7 :

```
sentence = codecs.open("D:\\Documents\\files\\sentence.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
sentence = sentence.read()

> This is my sentence in the right format
```

However, when I pass this text corpus to a list (for example, for tokenizing) :

```
tokens = sentence.tokenize()
```

and print it in the notebook, I obtain bit-like caracters, like :

```
(u'\ufeff\ufeffFaux,', u'Tunisie')
(u'Tunisie', u"l'\xc9gypte,")
```

Whereas I would like normal characters just like in my original import.

So my question is : how can I pass unicode objects to a list without having strange bit/ASCII characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all in how you `print`.  Python 2 displays lists using ASCII-only characters and substituting backslash escape codes for non-ASCII characters.  This is to make it easy to see hidden characters that normal printing would make invisible, like the double byte-order-mark (BOM) `\ufeff` you see in your strings.  Printing individual string items will display them correctly.

#### Many examples

Original strings:

```
>>> s = (u'\ufeff\ufeffFaux,', u'Tunisie')
>>> t = (u'Tunisie', u"l'\xc9gypte,")
```

Displaying at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> s
(u'\ufeff\ufeffFaux,', u'Tunisie')
>>> t
(u'Tunisie', u"l'\xc9gypte,")
>>> print s
(u'\ufeff\ufeffFaux,', u'Tunisie')
>>> print t
(u'Tunisie', u"l'\xc9gypte,")
```

Printing individual strings from the tuples:

```
>>> print s[0]
﻿﻿Faux,
>>> print s[1]
Tunisie
>>> print t[0]
Tunisie
>>> print t[1]
l'Égypte,
>>> print ' '.join(s)
﻿﻿Faux, Tunisie
>>> print ' '.join(t)
Tunisie l'Égypte,
```

A way to print tuples without escape codes:

```
>>> print "('"+"', '".join(s)+"')"
('﻿﻿Faux,', 'Tunisie')
>>> print "('"+"', '".join(t)+"')"
('Tunisie', 'l'Égypte,')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, `codecs.open(...)` returns a "wrapped version of the underlying file object" then you overwrite this variable with the result from executing the read method on that object. Brave, irritating - but ok ;-)

When you type say an äöüß into your "notebook", does it show like "this" or do you see some `\uxxxxx` instead?

The default value for `codecs.open(...)` is `errors=strict` so if this is the **same environment** for all samples, this should work.

I understand, that when you write "print it" you print the list, that is different from printing the content of the list.

Sample (taking a tab typed as `\t` into a normal "byte" string - this is python 2.7.11):

```
>>> a="\t"
>>> print a  # below is an expanded tab

>>> a
'\t'
>>> [a]
['\t']
>>> print [a]
['\t']
>>> for element in [a]:
...     print element
... 

>>> # above is an expanded tab
```